# How to build this flower?

Tags: part-identification, building

I found this picture of a flower in a book and would like to build it. I'm wondering what's inside the white bloom?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems to me this would be made something like pictured below. Obviously flower stems need to be rotated for better alignment and may need to attach an extra [*apollo* stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=85861#T=C) brick to make some space.

[image]

Key parts:

- [Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Studs on 4 Sides](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4733#T=C)
- [Plant Flower Stem with Bar and 6 Stems](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=19119#T=C). Other [options](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=flower%20stem#T=A).
- [Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Flower Edge (4 Knobs / Petals)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=33291#T=C) **or** [Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Flower Edge (5 Petals)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=24866#T=C)
- [Plate 1 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3024#T=C&C=12)

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

There is a very similar design to this tree used in the [10247 Ferris Wheel](https://brickset.com/sets/10247-1/Ferris-Wheel) set. (Page 96)

[image]

It uses another part [(6081986) Bar 6L with Stop Ring](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=63965&name=Bar%20%20%206L%20with%20Stop%20Ring&category=%5BBar%5D#T=C) which cannot be seen which strengthens the connections between the round bricks to stop it from snapping.